# How to prove that the subset sum problem is polynomially reducible to the knapsack problem

Tags: np-complete, knapsack-problems, subset-sum, polynomial-time-reductions

I want to prove that the **subset sum** problem is polynomially reducible to the **Knapsack problem**.
 Overall I want to show that **Knapsack is NP-complete**.
There are two parts to showing knapsack is NP-complete

1. knapsack is in NP
2. If I show that the subset sum problem is polynomially reducible to the knapsack. 
   Then since subset sum problem is known to be NP-hard. Knapsack is NP-Hard

Both 1) and 2) imply that Knapsack is NP-Complete

1. Is trivial as given any sequence of items we can verify the sum of their value 
   and weights in linear time. So the knapsack is in NP. Correct me If I am wrong here.

How do I approach 2)? I am not sure how to phrase the polynomial conversion
from the subset sum problem to the knapsack.

Comment: Both of these problems have a lot of different formulations. For example, for subset sum problem: "Given a multiset $S$ of positive integers and an integer $x$, find whether there is a sub(multi)set of $S$ with sum $x$". And for knapsack: "Given a multiset $S$ of positive integers and integer $W$, find a sub(multi)set of $S$ with maximum sum which is not greater than $W$". Can you see a reduction for such formulations?

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev For the knapsack formulation, shouldn't it say "with maximum sum of weights is not greater than $W$"?

Answer (score 1):

The **subset-sum** problem is a pair $(S,k)$ and a question whether there exists $S' \subset S$ such that $\sum_{s \in S'} s = k$.

The **knapsack** problem is a tuple $(w,v,W, V)$ that is weights, values, the knapsack capacity and the target value, and a question can you pick such a set of items $\mathcal{I}$ such that:

1. $\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} w_i \leq W$
2. $\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} v_i \geq V$

**Hint:** Given an instance $(S,k)$ of **subset-sum**, is there a way to set the weights and values of our items in the **knapsack**, so that these inequalities turn into a single equality related somehow to $k$?

Comment: So if I take all w = v =S and W,V=k  then this is an instance of knapsack problem. And a solution to it would give a solution to the subset problem. Is that correct?

Comment: That is exactly correct :D!

Comment: Is that all ? I mean than the proof is done right? Because knapsack is in NP and I have reduced subset to knapsack and so knapsack is NP Hard. Hence knapsack is NP Complete.. I thought it will be way more tougher than that. Thanks your way of putting the definition helped

Comment: Formally, to prove that a reduction is complete you have to show that every "yes-instance" of language $A$ gets transformed into a "yes-instance" of language $B$, and every "no-instance" into a "no-instance". This reduction is very simple, so the proof is just two lines of reasoning, but there are many reductions which are way more complicated than that

Comment: I have one more doubt. When a problem is NP complete does that mean that `there cannot be any polynomial algorithm for it `  or `no known polynomial time solution is known`?

Comment: As of today the problem $P = NP$ that is, "is there some problem in NP with no polynomial algorithm?" is unkown to be either true or false, although it is assumed to be false (that is $P \neq NP$) by many

Comment: Thanks! One last question. When we say that knapsack is in NP by simply stating that we can sum over the weights and values in polynomial time. Suppose the no. of weights/values = n could we equivalently say that we can sum over weights and values in 2n steps n steps each? and 2 steps for checking the inequality so the verification can be done in a total of **2n+2 steps** which is a polynomial. Is that correct? Because at some places it is said like - `For any arithmetic problem, it is important to note that our standard encoding assumes that the input integers are coded in binary`

Comment: Generally, if a solution is polynomial you don't care what polynomial it is. The "integers are coded in binary" is needed, because one could represent integers in unary (that is the number $n$ is represented as $n$ ones) and then one could actually solve subset-sum in time polynomial with respect to input size. This is why subset-sum (and knapsack) are called "weak-NP-complete" problems.